# loaded die algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I want an algorithm to simulate this loaded die:

the probabilities are: 
1: 1/18
2: 5/18
3: 1/18
4: 5/18
5: 1/18
6: 5/18

It favors even numbers.

My idea is to calculate in matlab the possibility of the above.
I can do it with 1/6 (normal die), but I am having difficulties applying it for a loaded die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way: generate two random numbers: first one is from 0 to 5 (0: odd, 1 - 5: even), which is used to determine even or odd. Then generate a second between 0 and 2, which determines exact number within its category. For example, if the first number is 3 (which says even) and second is 2 (which says the third chunk, 1-2 is a chunk, 3-4 is another chunk and 5-6 is the last chunk), the the result is 6.

Another way: generate a random number between 0 and 17, then you can simply / 6 and % 6 and use those two numbers to decide. For example, if /6 gives you 0, then the choice is between 1 and 2, then if % 6 == 0, the choice lands on 1, otherwise lands on 2.

Answer (score 2):

In matlab:

```
 ceil(rand*3)*2-(rand>(5/6))
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution:

Use [roulette wheel selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection)

```
n = generate number between 0 and sum( probabilities )
s = 0;
i = 0;
while s <= n do
  i = i + 1;
  s = s + probability of element i;
done
```

After the loop is done i will be the number of the chosen element. This works for any kind of skewed probability distribution, even when you have weights instead of a probability and want to skip normalizing.

Answer (score -1):

In the concise language of [J](http://jsoftware.com/),

```
>:3(<([++:@])|)?18
```